# webRequest api: does not handle requests to favicon.ico

Tags: google-chrome-extension, webrequest

I have a Google Chrome [extension](https://github.com/chestozo/faviconer) that I wrote when webRequest Extensions API was at experimental stage.
Currently I am rewriting it and I have noticed, that it does not handle requests to `/favicon.ico`.

**UPD** it handles this request only when Dev Tools panel is opened.

It handles all other requests (that I tested) except this.

I use:

`chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(handler, filter)`

to listen to all requests going from my browser. Filter value is set to handle all requests:

`var filter = { urls: [ "*://*/*" ] };`

Is this a known bug?

It may be caused by the way Chrome optimizes it's storage of sites favicons (I mean by loading favicons from it's cache like so: `chrome://favicon/http://yandex.ru`)

---

**References**

webRequest API http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/webRequest.html

Comment: After updating Chrome to the latest version (that is 18.0.1025.168 currently) - all works fine!